# AWS: How should VPC Endpoint for EC2 be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

### Question

Why do we need VPC Endpoint for EC2?
How should it be used?

### My understanding

VPC Endpoint is a service that enables services inside VPC to access outside VPC through AWS network.

For example... (See the screenshot, black thin lines)
We assume that we have a Lambda function in a private subnet and want the function to access S3.

Without VPC Endpoint: Lambda function --> NAT Gateway --> Internet Gateway -(via Internet)-> S3 bucket
With VPC Endpoint: Lambda function --> VPC Endpoint -(via AWS network)-> S3 bucket

[image: With/without VPC Endpoint]

### Problem

I find VPC Endpoint for EC2 (service name: `com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-1.ec2` in Singapore region). EC2 instances are always in a specific VPC, so now I do not understand why VPC Endpoint for EC2 is needed.

Does it work like: Lambda function --> VPC Endpoint -(via AWS network)-> EC2 instance (not in VPC)?
This is wrong if I understand the settings of EC2 instances correctly.

Comment: *"EC2 are always in a specific VPC"* - no. The EC2 *instance* is in a VPC, but not the EC2 *service*.

Comment: @luk2302 I updated the question. I mean EC2 instance. Or do you mean VPC Endpoint `com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-1.ec2` is for EC2 service?

Comment: Yes, the VPC endpoint is for the service, not for connecting to any instances.

Comment: The VPC endpoint for S3 in AWS is basically a checkbox that tells AWS to not charge you for bandwidth between S3 and your ec2 instances.

Comment: @luk2302 Can I know what exactly EC2 service is? I'm not sure how it can be used.

Comment: @jordanm do you mean the traffic doesn't go out of AWS network even when we don't use VPC Endpoint?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html - you wanna create a VPC, terminate an instance, set up a NACL, ... that is what the EC2 *service* does.

Comment: If you don't use the VPC endpoint, traffic from ec2 to s3 goes through the internet and you get charged for that.